# Facebook Graph API get comment count for multiple urls in one request

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get the comment count of multiple urls by doing one HTTP request? To get the comment count of one url at the time, I use the following url:

https://graph.facebook.com/https://www.google.com/

According to the documentation, you need to use "batch=" but this does not work. If it is possible, could you please supply an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#multiidlookup

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=https://www.google.com/,http://example.com/
```

Make sure to apply proper URL encoding to the individual URLs, to avoid problems with characters that have a special meaning in the URL query string. So that request above should look like this,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F,http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F
```